# Why is this not a well-defined $\Delta$-complex of the torus?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

My lectures notes say that the second diagram isn't a well-defined $\Delta$-complex of the torus because the $2$-simplices aren't totally ordered.

[image]

I don't really understand what that means.

Let's call the upper $2$-simplex $U$, the lower one $L$, the vertical $1$-simplex $a$, the horizontal one $b$ and the diagonal one $c$.

If we orient the top $2$-simplex clockwise and the bottom one counter-clockwise. Then the boundary of the top one is $a+b+c$ and the boundary of the second one is $-a-b-c$.

So where's the problem? Why is the first diagram well-defined, and the second one not?

Comment: this is actually a question that I was struggling with only a day or two ago, so I'm glad I could help! feel free to let me know if there's anything else you're not sure about :)

Comment: thanks! I was confused because I was thinking that all the vertices would get identified as the same one

Comment: They do when we actually glue the edges together, but the idea is (sort of, and somebody please do correct me if I'm wrong) that we construct the torus as a $\Delta$-complex by first constructing a square as a $\Delta$-complex, then identifying the sides. So it is the structure *before* the gluing that we care about, but we **also** want the gluing to preserve this structure, i.e. the ordering of the vertices.

Comment: Thinking about it that way means that the second diagram is 'ok' for the torus, but becomes 'not-ok' when we unglue it and look at the square we defined it on. The first diagram is 'ok' as a torus, and is *still* ok as a square after ungluing.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's ignore the side identification for a bit, and just take a look at the following picture, where the orange arrows represent the orientation of a line (a $1$-simplex):
[image: square]

On the left-hand side we see that we can label the vertices $v_i$ in such a way that the numbering agrees with the arrows.
That is, if we go along a line in the direction of an arrow, then we go from a smaller number to a bigger one, and vice versa.
This corresponds to the fact that we require that the restriction of $n$-simplices to their faces ($n-1$-simplices) *must respect the ordering of the vertices* ($0$-simplices).

Try labelling the diagram on the right in the same way -- see if it's possible.

Answer (score 5):

For a $\Delta$-complex the orientation of each simplex is given by a linear order on its vertices, the faces then have to be oriented accordingly. Hence, the $1$-faces of a simplex can never be oriented in a cyclic manner.